# After applying Reset CSS <em>, <code> and other tags lost their default style

Tags: css, css-reset

I found that I should be using Reset CSS file for making websites, but after I include it, all the `<em>` and `<code>` tags lose their style. `<em>` is not longer italic and `<code>` is no longer constant font.

I fixed it by adding `em { font-style: italic; }`, but I can't possibly add this for all the tags that lost their style?

Any ideas why?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: well.. that is the point of the reset CSS ... You can edit it and remove certain reset rules, or apply new one to them...

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that I was allowed to edit it! (I thought it was to be used as is, never meant to be changed). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple way will be to remove the styles from reset that you don't want *re-styled* or want to preserve. Reset css does not mean that you can not customize or delete anything from it.

Answer (score 2):

I found CSS resets to be a pain. In the end, you basically put back the styles that were already there by default. It's much easier to just style the elements as needed.

[No CSS Reset](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset/)

> The problem I've had with these resets is that I then find myself declaring much more than I ever needed to just to get browsers back to rendering things the way I want. As it turns out, I'm perfectly happy with how a number of elements render by default. I like lists to have bullets and strong elements to have bolded text.

Comment: The point of resets is that different browsers don't render the same tags the same way by default.  Saying you're happy with "the default" kind of misses the point; there are many defaults.

Comment: I'm very happy with "the default" and no it doesn't "miss the point". Your site "shouldn't" look the same in all browsers. It should be "similar" yes, but not "exactly" the same (http://24ways.org/2009/ignorance-is-bliss) ;)